# XMEGA384C3 ISR load

Tags: avr

I am using an XMEGA384C3 running at 32MHZ in a design with two USARTS. They both will be receiving data about every 150mS and using a protocol that contains a CRC16. In my USART receive ISR, I do my protocol decoding, but I am hesitant to do the CRC16 inside the ISR. Is this too much overhead in an ISR? I'm trying to figure out where I should do the CRC16 check/calc that won't take up too much time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can profile the CRC computation and make sure it takes less than 1/2 byte transfer time for the longest packet you'll be sending.  If it takes longer than 1/2 byte time, then you could have issues if you do it in the UART receive ISR.

My recommendation would be to use the UART ISR only to place received bytes into queues and then to do the packet-level decoding in a periodic timer ISR, setting the UART ISR at a higher priority level so you won't drop any bytes.